# Python syntax checkers that test edge cases

Tags: python, syntax-checking

Are there syntax checkers able to detect broken code based on edge cases. An example:

```
def run():
    for j in [0, 1]:
        if j == 0:
            yield j
        else:
            yield None


for i in run():
    print i * 2
```

This code is broken because `None * 2` does not make sense. Are there tools to detect this kind of error ?

Thank you

Comment: `NameError: j is not defined` or something when you run it.

Comment: `Line 10: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Comment: This is not a syntax error; this is a run-time semantic error.

Comment: No, your code is syntactically correct so no syntax checker can detect any problems in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a type checker, not a syntax checker.  Here's one attempt to make one: http://mypy-lang.org/

Answer (score 1):

You need a type checker, not a syntax checker. [github.com/python/mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy)